# ActionScript 3 enemy shooting three bullets and having them go in different directions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am learning as3 and I am kind of new to this. I am trying to get my enemy to shoot three bullets and so far I got that part done. However, I am stuck on making them go in different directions and they all just go in one directions instead. Here is an example of the code I am using in as3.

```
var _enemy:Enemy; 
_enemy = new Enemy(350,500);
addChild(_enemy);
enemyArray.push(_enemy);

for(var i:int = 0; i < enemyArray.length; i++)
{`enter code here`}

var _enemyFire:EnemyFire; 
_enemyFire = new EnemyFire(_enemy.x, _enemy.y);
addChild(_enemyFire);
enemyAmmoArray.push(_enemyFire);

for(var ef:int = 0; ef < enemyAmmoArray.length; ef++)
{
 _enemyFire = enemyAmmoArray[ef];
 _enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(0,5);
}
```

the

```
_enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(0,5);
```

is pulling up a function in the EnemyFire Class

```
public function enemyBulletMOV(MOVx:Number, MOVy:Number)
{
  x = x + MOVx;
  y = y + MOVy;
}
```

so I figured out that if I did this

```
 var _enemyFire:EnemyFire;

 _enemyFire = new EnemyFire(_enemy.x, _enemy.y);
    addChild(_enemyFire);
    enemyAmmoArray.push(_enemyFire);

 _enemyFire = new EnemyFire(_enemy.x, _enemy.y);
    addChild(_enemyFire);
    enemyAmmoArray.push(_enemyFire);

 _enemyFire = new EnemyFire(_enemy.x, _enemy.y);
    addChild(_enemyFire);
    enemyAmmoArray.push(_enemyFire);
```

I would get three bullets for the enemy but where I am stuck is this

```
_enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(-5,5);
_enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(0,5);
_enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(5,5);
```

I am stuck on giving each bullet it's own direction. instead they will only go one direction.

```
_enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(-5,5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another argument to your `EnemyFire` constructor:

```
_enemyFire = new EnemyFire(_enemy.x, _enemy.y, -5);
addChild(_enemyFire);
enemyAmmoArray.push(_enemyFire);
```

Then, in your `enemyBulletMOV` call:

```
_enemyFire.enemyBulletMOV(_enemyFire.direction,5);
```

That way you'll have the direction defined for each bullet.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying so many things and I was running in to dead ends.